# Passing date through hyperlink in Rdlc Report

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, rdlc

I want to redirect to a page from Rdlc report through hyperlink in a report.it have three parameters id , Startdate, Enddate. Date is not casting properly as it disable hyperlink from column and it doesn't work any suggestion. I casted date in many ways but it does'nt much helpfull.

help please

Comment: Please post your code it should be helpful4

Comment: ="http://localhost:9001/Pages/Trainee/TraineeAttendanceReport.aspx? STID=" & Fields!StudentID.Value &
 "&SDID=" & CDate(Fields!StartDate.Value).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

Comment: this is query string

Comment: Fieldvalue is string ...your casting "string to string" to it "String TO DATETIME AND DATETIME TO STRING

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Convert.ToDatetime(FieldVlaue).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

Comment: it is not working in my case